# Iterate thru distance then average

Tags: python, csv, average, distance

I have a csv (10k records) and I need to iterate thru a length of distance then average scores related to each length. Thus, group distances between 0ft and 0.009ft, then find an average score for that length. Group 0.01ft to 0.019ft, then find average score. Find average score at each distance of an increment of 0.01ft:

```
  feet, score
    0, 5
    0.001, 10
    0.002, 15
    0.003, 20
    0.004, 5
    0.006, 10
    0.008, 20
    0.009, 20
    0.01, 5
    0.011, 10
    0.012, 10
    0.013, 20
    0.013, 15
    0.014, 20
    0.016, 45
    0.017, 5
    0.018, 20
    0.019, 10
    0.02, 20
```

Then write to average to another csv:

```
  feet, score
    0, 13.125
    0.01, 16
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try truncating to two decimal places

Answer (score 0):

something like this (where a.csv is your 500 lines csv):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

STEP = 0.01

data = defaultdict(list)

with open('a.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    entries = sorted([entry for entry in reader][1:], key=lambda x: float(x[0]))
    for idx, entry in enumerate(entries):
        entry = [x for x in entry if x]
        feet = float(entry[0])
        score = float(entry[1].strip())
        if idx == 0 or feet - key >= STEP:
            key = feet
        data[key].append(score)
for k, v in data.items():
    print('{} -> {}'.format(k, sum(v) / len(v)))
```

output

```
0.0 -> 0.6259896916000001
0.01 -> 0.7254650324999999
0.02 -> 0.7559232991818182
0.031 -> 0.7564042394999999
0.041 -> 0.7016050595454545
0.052 -> 0.5817978843000001
0.062 -> 0.7553227885454544
0.073 -> 0.7331994431
0.083 -> 0.8406338765454549
0.094 -> 0.9791227943636365
0.105 -> 1.828199575
0.115 -> 1.6872732038181821
0.126 -> 1.6354184960000002
0.136 -> 1.6679616310909091
0.147 -> 1.8575009561000002
0.157 -> 1.8417512092000003
0.167 -> 1.8340773533636365
0.178 -> 1.8425028184000003
0.188 -> 2.1295739866
0.198 -> 2.6459379091818183
0.209 -> 2.3828843276000002
0.219 -> 2.3275099136999997
0.229 -> 2.4417235993636366
0.24 -> 2.4380506703
0.25 -> 2.5371588253000006
0.26 -> 2.4149494077000004
0.27 -> 2.2936866909000004
0.28 -> 2.437273469181818
0.291 -> 2.3236982016
0.301 -> 2.4022541664
0.311 -> 2.3130940562
0.321 -> 2.5310746604
0.331 -> 2.2081656021000002
0.341 -> 2.2971205086363637
0.352 -> 2.2664439074000002
0.362 -> 2.2577037961000004
0.372 -> 2.3274537939
0.382 -> 2.3944920092000004
0.392 -> 2.4642428165
0.402 -> 2.463620020181818
0.413 -> 2.3945957363000003
0.423 -> 2.4159163421
0.433 -> 2.4741425820000003
0.443 -> 2.5781124094999996
0.453 -> 2.4061227924
0.463 -> 2.465448882181818
0.474 -> 2.447893211090909
0.484 -> 2.4245401217
0.494 -> 2.5651068714000003
```

Comment: balderman's code works, but stops at 0.02. I need it to continue looping thru the list, so it output averages for: 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 . . . 500.1

Comment: `a.csv` is the data you have posted in the question (few records only). Did you try this code with your 10K records?

Comment: balderman, thanks for the help! I did, but the step only averages 0-0.009, 0.01-0.019, and then stops at 0.02. I need it to continue: 0.02-0.029, 0.03-0.039, etc

Comment: Can you upload the first 200 lines of the file to somewhere? (Pastebin)

Comment: changed line 13 to:     score = float(entry[1])

Comment: @sam Code was fixed and works against the 500 lines csv

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a quick solution to your problem (excluding the .csv part) that might help you. I am sure there is a nice list comprehension aswell.

```
data = [[0, 5], [1.2, 10], [0.01, 10]]
bounds = [0.1, 1, 2] # Just fill in your (upper) bounds here
grouped = []

# Create a new list with the first values "grouped"
for row in data:    # go through .csv file
    for i, upper_bound in enumerate(bounds):
        if row[0] <= upper_bound:
            grouped.append([bounds[i], row[1]])
            break

# Calculate the average for every group
for i, upper_bound in enumerate(bounds):
    amount = 0
    sum = 0
    for row in grouped:
        if row[0] == upper_bound:
            sum += row[1]
            amount += 1
    try:
        avg = (sum / amount)
        print(str(upper_bound) + ' --> ' + str(sum / amount))
    except: # divided by zero
        print(str(upper_bound) + ' --> 0')
```